# Rails db migrate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I started to write an api in rails. I want to migrate my model to db, but I get this error:

```
E:\WebAuction\Backend\api>rails db:migrate
rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

you can't redefine the primary key column 'id'. To define a custom primary key, pass { id: false } to create_table.
E:/WebAuction/Backend/api/db/migrate/20180516070242_create_wa_players.rb:4:in `block in change'
E:/WebAuction/Backend/api/db/migrate/20180516070242_create_wa_players.rb:3:in `change'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ArgumentError: you can't redefine the primary key column 'id'. To define a custom primary key, pass { id: false } to create_table.
E:/WebAuction/Backend/api/db/migrate/20180516070242_create_wa_players.rb:4:in `block in change'
E:/WebAuction/Backend/api/db/migrate/20180516070242_create_wa_players.rb:3:in `change'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
== 20180516070242 CreateWaPlayers: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:wa_players)
```

My Model class

```
class WaPlayer < ApplicationRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  def change
    create_table :wa_players, :id => false do |t|
      t.id :String
      t.playerName :String
      t.uuid :String
      t.password :String
      t.money :String
      t.itemsSold :String
      t.itemsBought :String
      t.earnt :String
      t.spent :String
      t.Permissions :String
      t.Locked :String
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :wa_players, :id
  end
end
```

If someone knows how to fix, please tell me how.

Comment: it would be good for you to have understanding on basics rubyonrails model, migration concept.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know where you are getting your activerecord knowledge from, but you seem to have messed it up. It's not a `t.<column> <type>`. It is `t.<type> <column>`.

```
t.string :id
t.string :player_name
```

And so on.

(Note: most names in ruby follow snake_case naming convention, not camelCase).

Comment: @LarsErhardt it won't work if you change only these two lines, you need to change whole lines

Comment: heres the whole err: https://pastebin.com/RAstaWVs Ive changed all lines in the schema t.string :id and so on

Comment: @LarsErhardt: try `t.string :id, primary_key: true`

Comment: Funny to pass me code thats reproducing the same error https://pastebin.com/9Y98gwhZ

Comment: @LarsErhardt: well, this _should_ work. If you make a [mcve] (say, a stripped down rails app, pushed to github), I'll take a look.

Comment: @LarsErhardt: wait wait wait, what is your `change` method doing in the MODEL? Show me the migration!

Comment: @LarsErhardt: yeah, your migration is off. Apply the abovementioned advice to the migration file.

Comment: advice? what do you mean? can you tell me the exactly order?

Comment: @LarsErhardt: the `primary_key: true` and the `id: false`. Also snake_case.

Answer (score 0):

It will be `t.string` then `column_name` like

```
def change
    create_table :wa_players, :id => false do |t|
      t.string :id
      t.string :player_name
      t.string :uuid
      t.string :password
      t.string :money
      t.string :items_sold
      t.string :items_bought
      t.string :earnt
      t.string :spent
      t.string :permissions
      t.string :locked
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :wa_players, :id, unique: true
end
```

Look at that [**`Creating a Table`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-table)

**Update**

I don't know how you trying but follow these steps

1. run your console like `rails g model WaPlayer`
2. Go to `db/migrate/TIMESTAMP_create_wa_players.rb`
3. Then paste this `change` method into `class`
4. Then run `rails db:migrate` or `rake db:migrate` after `rake db:create` if you did not create the DB till now

Comment: first time i am working with this, my boss asked me if i have some programming knowledge and he told me to write that programm for him

Comment: @fool-dev look at above question he is writing migration code inside model.

Comment: @LarsErhardt Follow the ***Update*** section and try this

Comment: Remove this line `add_index :wa_players, :id` and try again

Answer (score 0):

From the content provided, it seems like you are heading the wrong way:

Firstly, generating migration for model which seems you have done it as you have shared the model class.

Model Class

```
class WaPlayer < ApplicationRecord::Base
 has_secure_password
end
```

Thus, there would be migration for the same ie:

```
def change
 create_table :wa_players, :id => false do |t|
  t.id :String
  t.playerName :String
  t.uuid :String
  t.password :String
  t.money :String
  t.itemsSold :String
  t.itemsBought :String
  t.earnt :String
  t.spent :String
  t.Permissions :String
  t.Locked :String
  t.timestamps null: false
  end
 add_index :wa_players, :id
end
```

The contents of the migration are wrong which needs to be updated with:

```
def change
 create_table :wa_players, :id => false do |t|
  t.string :id
  t.string :player_name
  t.string :uuid
  t.string :password
  t.string :money
  t.string :items_sold
  t.string :items_bought
  t.string :earnt
  t.string :spent
  t.string :permissions
  t.string :locked
  t.timestamps null: false
 end
  add_index :wa_players, :id
end
```

Now you need to run

```
rake db:create
```

if the db has not been migrated else run

```
rake db:migrate.
```

Comment: remove the add_index line from migration and  modify t.string :id with t.string :id, index: true and then check again.

Comment: def change
 create_table :wa_players, :id => false do |t|
  t.string :id, index: true
  t.string :player_name
  t.string :uuid
  t.string :password
  t.string :money
  t.string :items_sold
  t.string :items_bought
  t.string :earnt
  t.string :spent
  t.string :permissions
  t.string :locked
  t.timestamps null: false
 end
end

Comment: Ok Mr Troll, theres the same error again.....https://pastebin.com/RcgQEy51

Comment: It seems like the migration you are trying to run has already been migrated